# Why I got error Class 'Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot' not found after automatically uploading to our dev server?

Tags: laravel, git, ubuntu-server

Using use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot
after I upload with git my changes to bitbucket and the changes automatically uploaded to
our dev server (I do not know how it is implemented it was done by other people) I got error

```
Class 'Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot' not found
```

when refered code:

```
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot as SpatieBrowsershot;
...
        createDir([public_path() . '/upload', public_path() . '/upload/pdf_tmp']);
        SpatieBrowsershot::html(htmlspecialchars_decode($pdf_content))
            ->showBrowserHeaderAndFooter()
            // ->headerHtml('<div style="height:240px !important;"><h3>Receipt Voucher</h3></div>')
            ->footerHtml($footerHtml)
            ->showBackground()
            ->margins(20, 10, 20, 10)
```

I need in ssh git to remove manually ‘/vendor’, ‘composer.lock’ and remove files
inside of ‘bootstrap/cache’ and tun

```
composer install
```

after that I have no this error, untill next automatic upload(If not to make steps above )
In composer.json on server and on my local ubuntu 18 I have :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.38",
    "spatie/browsershot": "^3.37",
```

Why this error and how it can be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: delete your packages locally then run composer install, does that break it too?

Comment: Instead of deleting the `vendor` folder and stuff, does `composer install` suffice and make it work? Maybe the "other people" forgot to implement `composer install` when uploading to the dev server. Maybe you could just ask them how it's done

Comment: I did got catch your idea. Could you please explain why it has to help ?  Also file package-lock.json is not in root  .gitignore of my project.

Comment: @brombeer , thanks for your gint. Could  ity be issue of the problem ?

Comment: I have no idea. If they forgot to install new packages added by composer that sure would be the issue